# Why does generator only advances once with for loop?

Tags: python, python-3.x, linked-list, generator, yield

I'm surprised I could not find anything similar on the internet.

```py
class Node:
    def __init__(self, value):
        self.value = value
        self.prev = None
        self.next = None

class DoublyLinkedList:
    def __init__(self):
        self.head = None
        self.tail = None

    # bunch of other methods here removed for clarity

    def removeNodesWithValue(self, value):
        for node in self._getAllNodes(value):
            print('removing')
            self._remove(node)

    # I haven't provided this method before I got the answer
    def _remove(self, node):
        ...
        node.prev = None
        node.next = None
        ...

    def _getAllNodes(self, value):
        cur = self.head
        while cur is not None:
            if cur.value == value:
                yield cur
            cur = cur.next

if __name__ == '__main__':
    l = DoublyLinkedList()
    l.insertAfter(l.head, Node(1))
    l.insertAfter(l.head, Node(1))
    l.insertAfter(l.head, Node(1))
    l.removeNodesWithValue(1)
```

This code prints this:

```
removing
```

But I expect it to print it 3 times for each found node.
Now, if I change this line `for node in self._getAllNodes(value)` to this `for node in list(self._getAllNodes(value))`, only then it prints it 3 times as expected.

Does anyone have any clue on why the for loop only takes one element from the generator and not all 3?

Full code: https://pastebin.com/QEasZSnK

**Update**:

As per ShadowRanger's answer, changing `_getAllNodes` to this fixes the issue:

```py
def _getAllNodes(self, value):
    cur = self.head
    while cur is not None:
        next = cur.next
        if cur.value == value:
            yield cur
        cur = next
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You neglected to provide the definition of `remove`, but psychic debugging says it `None`s out the `next` attribute of the node it's removing. Problem is, your generator pauses at the `yield`, gives the node back to the caller, which then `remove`s it. When the generator resumes, it still has a reference to the removed node, and tries to get the `next` attribute from it, but that `next` is now `None`, so it looks like you're done immediately.

Solutions:

1. Cache the `next` *before* `yield`ing
2. Have `removeAllNodes` cache all the nodes to a `list` before removing
3. Just skip all this nonsense and set `self.head = self.tail = None` as the sole code in `removeAllNodes` and let the garbage collector handle cleaning up the now unreferenced nodes (this might not be immediate, if reference cycles are involved or you're not using the CPython reference interpreter, but it's usually fine to have a brief delay before cleanup; you could use `weakref` proxies of some sort for the reverse linkage to avoid cycles if needed)

Comment: Thanks for the answer! Full code is available through the link at the end of the post. However, your psychic debugging is genius! Works good now :)

Comment: Oh, and while I would use option 3 normally, this is just a silly programming problem that I solve once for fun, so I'll go with 1. This also allows me to skip setting those `None`s in other methods (e.g. in order to move a node from the middle to other place I need to first remove it and then insert)

Comment: @Sam: Okay, just a warning: This will change how mutations to the list during iteration are handled; by caching, an attempt to insert after the most recently `yield`ed node will be ignored (iteration will continue at the original next node). And if the `next` node is removed, rather than the current node, you'll get the same confusing early termination. This isn't necessarily wrong (mutating collections while iterating is frowned upon in general), just something to be aware of.